# MSSQL PDO Prepared Select Statement Failing when Static Succeeds

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

so I am working on a script that syncs two databases, and I know the code works if the PDO query that selects the rows is static, and not prepared. Upon altering the statement to be prepared and passing the variable that determines the start of the current record pull request, the code fails with the error below.

Error Code:

```
I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 10743 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [10743] (severity 15) [(null)]
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$offset = 0;
try 
{
$DBH = new PDO('dblib:host=obscured;dbname=obscured', 'obscured', 'obscured');
$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

if 
(
$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT COUNT(LocalSKU) FROM Inventory")
) 
{
    if ($STH->fetchColumn() > 0) 
    {
        $stmt = $DBH->query("SELECT COUNT(LocalSKU) FROM Inventory");
        $count = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $maxlimit = intval($count[0]['']);
        while ($offset < $maxlimit) 
        {
            $STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT LocalSKU, Price, Price2, Price3, Price4 FROM Inventory ORDER BY LocalSKU OFFSET ? ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY");
            $STH->execute(array($offset));
            $pricebracket = $STH->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $postdata = json_encode($pricebracket);
            $post = curl_init('obscured/price2.php');
            curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
            curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postdata)));
            $result = curl_exec($post);

            if (curl_errno($post)) 
            {
                die('Could not send request: '.curl_error($post));
            } 
            else
            {
                $resultStatus = curl_getinfo($post, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 

                if ($resultStatus == 200) 
                {
                    echo 'Bracket # '.$offset.'. Not as bad as it could be. HTTP Status code: '.$resultStatus.'<br />';
                } 
                else 
                {
                    die('Request failed: HTTP status code: '.$resultStatus);
                }
            }
            curl_close($post);
            $offset += 1000;
            $rows = array();
        }
    }
} 
} 
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
echo "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.<br />";
echo $e->getMessage();
}
$DBH = null;
?>
```

If the ? in the prepared statement is replaced with a 0, and the statement is run as a query instead of prepare, or even as a prepare with no variable passed through execute, the process succeeds. Unfortunately, it collects the same 1000 records and curls them 13 times to the receiving script, instead of groups of records (breaking up the 13,274 we have) and sending each 1000 record group.

Sensitive login credentials and filepaths have been replaced with the word obscured, however they are all valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this to tell PDO that you are binding an integer for it not to put `''` around the variable.

```
 $STH->bindParam(1, $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT)
 $STH->execute();
```